# Knockout JS - Any smart way to clear value when not visible?

Tags: knockout.js

I know I can check the value of `USDteUnk()` and then hard-code ViewModel.USDte("") to clear the value.

However, I am wondering, is there a smart way to clear the value when an element is not visible? I.e., when `Unsure [USDteUnk]` checked, clear `[USDte]`?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="USDte">4.1 Date of first scan?</label>
  <div id="USDteBox" data-bind="visible: USDteUnk() === '0' || USDteUnk() === ''">
    <input type="text" name="USDte" id="USDte" class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" data-bind="value: USDte">
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-blue">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="USDteUnk" id="USDteUnk" data-bind="bsChecked: USDteUnk"> Unsure
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The following is handler bsChecked as I use bootstrap button group, original Checked handler doesn't work.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bsChecked = {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
            viewModel, bindingContext) {
                var value = valueAccessor();
                if (ko.unwrap(value)==='-1')
                    $(element).closest('.btn').button('toggle');

                var newValueAccessor = function () {
                    return {
                        change: function () {
                            value(element.checked?'-1':'');
                        }
                    }
                };
                ko.bindingHandlers.event.init(element, newValueAccessor,
                allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
            },
            update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor,
            viewModel, bindingContext) {
                if ($(element).val() == ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) && !$(element).prop('checked')) {
                    $(element).closest('.btn').button('toggle');
                }
            }
        }
```

**SULTION BASED ON** @Tomalak Answer

```
            ko.applyBindings(VM);
            VM.OtherDetail().USDteUnk.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                if (newValue === '-1') {
                    VM.OtherDetail().USDte('');
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should include the `bsChecked` binding handler in your question.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, thanks for your help, I have added bsCheck handler in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a smart way to clear the value when an element is not visible? I.e., when Unsure [USDteUnk] checked, clear [USDte]?

Yes, via a [subscription](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables).

```
self.USDteUnk.subscribe(function (checked) {
    if (checked) self.USDte("");
});
```

Whether the element that displays the value of `USDte` is visible or not is completely irrelevant.